# Calculate End Date When Given Today Plus A Number

Tags: excel, google-drive-api, worksheet-function

I'm building a spreadsheet with formulas in Google Drive (although Excel would work too). And I have a calculated field that gives gives me a number of days until a project is complete (ex. 128).

I want to know, given that number, what date that is.

So Essentially, what date is 128 days from now (or whatever the number calculates out to).

Researching, I'm assuming I need to use the NetworkDays function, however, I can't figure out how to make it work when I don't have a start and an end date.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you want to add only `working` days to a date you can use WORKDAY function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=TODAY()+128
```

Where `128` is the number of days beyond today you want.